# how to make local domain name available to people on LAN

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system

IN my Ubuntu server i have My source Matrix installed.

I acces the page by typing

```
http://ubuntu.matrix.local
```

i want to access the same from other poeple computer on the same LAN.

How can i do that

my /etc/hosts file conatins

```
127.0.0.1   ubuntu.matrix.local
127.0.1.1   ubuntu
```

Comment: I don't know wether your question regarding Macs is answered but you just have to add the IP address and name in `/private/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only a few computers, just create a hosts file with the correct IP details and store in the appropriate place on those computers.  That is how people did things before DNS was invented!  If you have a large network, you surely have DNS somewhere...

Comment: i have few mac host as well , how cna i configure them

Comment: Check Apple Support pages at http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27291 for how to do the same thing on Macs

Answer (score 2):

That makes it available to your host, but not other people's hosts.  You need to either run a local DNS server and point all the clients to it (harder) or see if your router/NAT box will let you do what you want.

Comment: under what options will i be able to do that in router.
i have dns server installed on server.
I added the one forward lookup zone for that name and IP address.If i use ping ubuntu.matrix.local then it don't work but if i use
ping -a 10.0.11.121 then it identifies as ubuntu.matrix.local

Comment: When you already have a dns server, just add it to the configuration of your clients in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Every computer will have to use YOUR dns server, and that includes the machine running the server itself.  You will have to properly configure the zone, and then add the address records to it.  I suspect you need a primer on DNS.  Google should find a few thousand helpful articles.

Comment: i can use the ip address also to visit website but the problem is that if i type http://127.0.0.1 then apache server page comes and if i type
http://ubuntu.matrix.local then the main page comes. I don't know the path of main page file

Answer (score 1):

On a LAN, you could use [mDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking) if you don't want to setup a DNS server.

On Ubuntu (and Linux distributions in general), [Avahi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)) is responsible for managing mDNS requests. All the servers who need to access your machine will need to use an mDNS system also.

mDNS works by broadcasting the DNS request on the LAN so it doesn't depend on a centralized DNS server.

I would really advise you do use a DNS server (or at least to distribute a `/etc/hosts` file using Puppet for example), but mDNS can do if your need is limited.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use DNS server, like bind (apt-get install bind9) or djbdns (apt-get install djbdns).
In simple LAN environements, setting a DNS is pretty easy task.
You can learn a lot and have a lot of fun.